# How can I restart my @Scheduled annotated method?

Tags: java, spring, cron

I have the following scenario:

```
@Scheduled(...) 
public void method() {
  try {
    // Some business logic throws an error
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    log.error("UH_OH");
  }
}
```

When the error is caught in the try-catch block and logged down, I noticed that when the next scheduled time arrives, the @Scheduled method does not fire off.

I have the following question:

1. What is the possible reason(s) these are happening
2. I would like to know how I can re-start the schedule to make sure it fires off in the next run.

Comment: Are you sure that the previous task is finished?

Comment: Yes the previous task completed.